# Set Message as seen with Mailkit using Powershell

Tags: powershell, mailkit

I'm trying to write a script in PS to fetch all unseen/unread messages via imap and import them into a SQL-DB. After the import I want to set the message as seen and move it to a subfolder. Everything works fine, execpt I can't figure out, how to set a message as read.

I tried it with
`$Inbox_Folder.AddFlags($UID,([MailKit.MessageFlags]::Seen))`
but with that I get the error: [MimeKit.MimeMessage] does not contain a method named 'AddFlags'.

After some searching I found out that Add/Remove/SetFlags were replaced with Store. So I did a `$Inbox_Folder.Store($UID,[MailKit.MessageFlags]::Seen)`
which brings me to this error: Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Store" and the argument count: "2".
After some more digging I realized i need an IStoreFlagsRequest. But I simply can't figure out how to write that line in PS. Any help would really be appreciated.

Below is my script

```
 Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\MailKit.dll"
 Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\MimeKit.dll"
 $Mail_Server = '***'
 $Mail_Port = '***'
 $Mail_Username = '***'
 $Mail_Password = '***'
 $Imap_Client = New-Object MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient
 $Imap_Client.Connect($Mail_Server,$Mail_Port)
 $Imap_Client.Authenticate($Mail_Username,$Mail_Password)
 $Imap_Client.Inbox.Open([MailKit.FolderAccess]::ReadWrite) | Out-Null
 $Root_Folder = $Imap_Client.GetFolder($Imap_Client.PersonalNamespaces[0])
 $Inbox_Folder = $Root_Folder.GetSubfolder("INBOX")
 $Archive_Folder = $Inbox_Folder.GetSubfolder("Archiv")
 $Mail_UIDs = $Imap_Client.Inbox.Search([MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::AND([MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::NotSeen,[MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::New))
 if($Mail_UIDs.Count -gt 0)
  {
  ForEach($UID in $Mail_UIDs.GetEnumerator())
   {
   #do stuff
   $Inbox_Folder.AddFlags($UID,([MailKit.MessageFlags]::Seen)) #not working
   $Imap_Client.Inbox.MoveTo($UID,$Archive_Folder) | Out-Null #works
   }
  }
$Imap_Client.Disconnect($true)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, there have been changes in MailKit recently and most of the examples you will find are referring to the old (and now removed) `.addflags` method.

You are right about **store** being the correct interface, but you were still trying to use it like the old method, while it needs a `StoreFlagRequest` being passed a `StoreAction` and a `MessageFlag` :

```
$Inbox_Folder.Store($UID, [MailKit.StoreFlagsRequest]::new([MailKit.StoreAction]::Add,[MailKit.MessageFlags]::Seen))
```

or, (since Powershell will try cast the string to the corret types anyways), in a simpler way:

```
$Inbox_Folder.Store($UID, [MailKit.StoreFlagsRequest]::new("Add","Seen"))
```

the updated docs are (I've just tried googling that) the *only* updated reference at the time of writing:

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/README.md#deleting-messages-in-imap